# Microsoft Edgeにてtextareaの改行コードの扱いが不正

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVCでWebアプリケーションを作成していますが、
textarea内の改行が2倍になってしまう問題を解決したいと考えています。

Microsoft Edgeにて、textareaの中に改行を含んだ文字列を入力してPostし、このデータをDBに保存します。 (Postされたデータの改行コードは `\r\n`(CrLf) となっています)

これを再度textarea内に表示する際、Razorではこのように書いています。

```html
<textarea asp-for="Property" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
```

すると、表示される文字列（アスキーコード以外）はエンコードされた状態となります。
このとき、改行コードも`&#xD;&#xA;`とエンコードされているのですが、
これをEdgeで表示すると改行２つになります。
これを正しく改行１つにする方法はないでしょうか？

Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18363

例えば

```
a
bc
d
```

といった文字列は`a&#xD;&#xA;bc&#xD;&#xA;d`とエンコードされます。

尚、Google Chromeでは問題なく表示されることは確認しています。
DB保存する際に改行コードを `\n(Lf)` のみにすれば問題ないのは確認済みですが、
さすがにこのような特殊な対応は取りたくないのが本音です。

Comment: 同様の問題と思われるものが見つかりましたので、参考までにリンクを貼ります。ここでも解決はしていません。https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56386992/extra-line-feeds-in-textareas-issue-with-microsoft-edge-or-encodeforhtml-cold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTMLに`&#xD;`を入れるのは規格違反です。本来はサーバサイドで`\r`を除去するようなんとかすべきです。
ASP.NET MVC は触ったことがないのでサーバサイドの対処はわかりません。

規格違反とはいえ、クライアントサイドで対処するなら、

```js
<script>
let textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
let value = t.value;
textarea.value = '';
textarea.value = value;
</script>
```

というように、一度別の値で上書きしてから元の値をセットすると解消するようです。
DOM上では`\r`はまったく見えないので、「`value`から`\r`を消す」というアプローチはできません。

> 特殊な対応は取りたくないのが本音です。

でしたら、何もしないのがお勧めです。Chromium 版 Edge になったら解消するでしょうから。

Comment: HTMLに&#xD;を入れるのが規格違反であるというのは、どこで確認できますか？

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/C/#character-references の最後から2段落目です。

Comment: たしかにCRは除くとの記載がありますね。知りませんでした。たしかHTML4にはそのような条件はなかったと思いますが、変更になったのでしょうかね

Comment: その前段(12.1.3.1 Newlines)に、文字参照のLFは改行として扱うがCRはそうしない、との記載があります。今回の問題はEdgeがこれに従ってないことではあると思いますが...入力環境と表示環境が同一であるという前提ならば、改行コードをエンコードしないで出力するという方法がとれるんじゃないでしょうか

Comment: 規格違反ということであれば、無条件削除するコードを共通で入れてしまっても良いと思いました。ありがとうございました。